# Docker Desktop hangs, with tray icon text "Docker is starting"

Tags: docker-for-windows

After a computer restart and a Java runtime environment update, Docker Desktop hangs, with tray icon text "Docker is starting".

When using Docker in PowerShell, it says:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Right-clicking on the tray-icon opens the menu without the chance to click on anything, and the menu does not disappear anymore.
Docker Desktop does not show local images or containers.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was going into Windows Services (run `services.msc`), and stopping/starting the "**Docker Desktop service**".

[image]

Comment: I cannot test it, but you will not think this up. It seems as if this could do the same as the other answer, but is much easier. Therefore the check.

Answer (score 3):

On my side I had a similar issue on my Windows machine.

It was probably caused by a forced shutdown after sleep mode (perhaps no more battery).

I tried many things like restarting the Services but it was not working when I started to watch the folder `.docker` in my home directory.

I did this:

- I first stopped my Docker Desktop process
- then I deleted the file named `.token_seed.lock` in ${USER_HOME}/.docker/
- Start the Docker Desktop from the shortcut

and after that my Docker was running without any issue and my stored images were correctly displayed (and starting / stopping properly).

Comment: Could this be a placebo effect? Because in the end, you also just did the same as me, restart the computer = stop the docker process, start Docker Desktop again. I did not have to delete the `.token_seed.lock` and still it started to work again. Therefore I doubt that deleting that file is needed at all. It looks more like the usual "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" thing. Can anybody else say something about this?

Comment: Not really, because I notice the token_seed file was still there even after successive restart (docker desktop / docker services). But since I wrote this answer, many updates of the soft did make it more stable on this regard. (I got other issues but not related to the question). I would say the OS-X version is quite easier to use than with the WSL2, especially when recreating docker compose files several times.

Comment: Still not sure about this. I wait for other comments before I switch the accepted answer. I do not say that in your case this file was not there after restart, I rather guess that the file does play a role. Since I cannot reproduce this case, it is all too much of a guess only.

Comment: Don't worry about the accepted answer: I just wrote the answer as an alternative and because the "IT Crowd trick" I saw in many other posts did not really worked for me. I keep the answer just in case someone have the same issue and still with an old version. I think the issue is not here anymore (in the most recent releases) and very difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing this as a small note since I did not see the chance that waiting alone would be the trick in the end.

- Wait for a couple of minutes (five to ten!) when it hangs, it could be just an update.
- When the right-click menu has crashed and it still does not hide even after a good waiting time, it goes without saying that you need to restart the computer (or force restart Docker Desktop, untested). You will not damage Docker Desktop if you restart while it might update in the background, since in my case, I did that and it just updated again after restart.

I waited in the settings menu of Docker Desktop, with the "loading circle" going on, and I guess that is not needed. You can just wait anywhere. Thus, there seems to be no need to re-install Docker Desktop in such a case.

It is likely that it took so long to start Docker just because there was an **auto update** running - and no information about this. It hung after a restart of a computer (and then after updating Java JRE, which I thought to be the reason at first), and it is likely that the computer restart triggered the Docker Desktop auto update, see [this remark which happened in the same time frame](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8186#issuecomment-802952337).

Comment: There is a comment at [Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66695222/11154841) hinting at a Java issue: `Reverting the JAVA_PATH setting and it works for me`.